Objects Viewable on wireframe, Rendered and Material Preview Not visible in solid mode though

Sorry I don't really know how to explain this I was rescaling some objects and I scaled it down 1000 times. Some context I am designing a product and I tried to do some mesh editing. The objects scale was off so I tried to rescale it. I tried changing the clip start and end, I also have tried using shift + C to centre the view and home. However once I re-entered on the object it was invisible in the object shaded mode.
Any advice onto how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry but I don't know what else to do.
Edit -- I can see in x ray though, however I have also discovered I can't go into edit mode when any object is selected .
The Scale seems to be huge see below photo


Edit 2 after lowering the scale again even after pressing shift + C, numpad . and home I cannot find the object at all the clip start is 0.1 mm and the End is set to something huge like 1000 million mm and I still can't find the object.


Answer to anyone who may have the same issue
I had to reset the scale, and position of my parts back to 0 and 1
The scale was too small -4000 and position around 600000 mm
you can do this in the properties panel
be careful when moving the parts as blender can crash I had to Hide all of my parts pre move.


You might have found your solution, but there are surface glitches. This is due to your ridiculously wide range from Clip Start to End. Starting at 0.1 mm and ending at 1000015 m (or is it mm just cropped?). I have no idea how large your objects are, but I would recommend a difference of only 10^4 between them, like 0.1 m(!) and 1000 m. Of course depending on your object size. If it is just a few milimeters, then maybe 0.01 mm to 100 mm. Read more about it in the manual: Depth Buffer Glitches
